# Regex help. Capture string starting with "score" and ending with number

Tags: regex, preg-match

I've tried a lot before this post, but simple cannot put it to work, i need your help please.

Imagine the following string:

```
$str = "Games  >=  2  AND score  >= 30 and country = 2";
```

or

```
$str = "Games  >=  2  AND score  < 30 and country = 2";
```

or

```
$str = "Games  >=  2  AND (score  between 10 and 60) and country = 2";
```

or

```
$str = "Games  >=  2  AND score  between 10 and 60 and country = 2";
```

or

```
$str = "score  between 10 and 20 and Games  >=  2";
```

or

```
$str = "score  between 2 and 9 and Games  >=  2";
```

or

```
$str = "Games  >=  2  AND score = 3";
```

having my regex

```
$re = '/(score.*\d\d|score.*\d)/mi';

preg_match($re, one_of_those_strings_above, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

You can check here
https://regex101.com/r/6Nt3UX/3

i can capture what i want, but if the number is lower than 10 (in example between 2 and 9) the regex fail.

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you provide examples of regular expressions that did not work as expected?

Comment: @ggorlen i've updated the post, and provided a sample in regex101.com

Comment: @varontron  i've updated the post, and provided a sample in regex101.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears we need to be more specific.

```
(score\s*(?:[><]?=|between)\s*\d+(?:\s+and\s+\d+)?)
```

Explanation:

The whole regex returns only one group.  The `(?:...)` construct is a non-capturing group.

1. Starts with `score`
2. Followed by zero or more spaces `\s*` (in case you have `score=`)
3. Followed by a `>=`, `<=`, `=`, or `between`:  `[><]?=|between`
4. Followed by zero or more spaces `\s*`
5. Followed by one or more digits `\d+`
6. Followed by an optional string comprised of zero or more spaces followed by `and` followed by zero or more spaced followed by one or more digits. `(?:\s+and\s+\d+)?`

The specificity of `and\s+\d+` in the last non-capturing group eliminates the case where the 2nd score number is followed by a phrase like `and xyz = 5`

Comment: does not work because if you have

games  >=  2  AND score  between 2 and 2 and Pais = 2

it will grab  between 2 and 9 and Pais = 2

Comment: updated the regex to acccount for numbers following the score

Comment: That almost work but if you have score between 1 and 9 it does not work. Only works for numbers > 10. Example: score between 1 and 20

Comment: I have tried your code and It was not working properly for me. So I again updated your logic. 

`/(score\s*(?:[><]?=?|between)\s*\d+(?:\s+and\s+\d+)?)/g`

You can try and check it again over here. --> https://regex101.com/r/6Nt3UX/5

Comment: Thank you so much to you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/score.*(?<!\d)\d\d?(?!\d)/
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jAtYXJ/1/)

1. `score` Matches `score`.
2. `.*` A greedy, maximal match of 0 or more non-newline characters. Use flag `s` if you need `.` to match newline characters.
3. `(?<!\d)\d\d?(?!\d)` Matches one or two digits with the assertions that they are not preceded nor followed by any any other digits. So a maximal match is performed until either one or two digits is found.